# Flutter StreamBuilder not updating when data is changed

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently using the Firebase realtime database and a stream builder to listen to changes like so:

```
late var stream = FirebaseDatabase.instance
     .reference()
     .child("devices")
     .child(user_id);
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: StreamBuilder<Event>(
         stream: stream.onValue,
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
           print('stream updated');
           if (snapshot.hasData &&
               !snapshot.hasError &&
               snapshot.data?.snapshot.value != null) {
             var data = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value;
             handler.updateData(data);
           }
           return Column(
```

When the widget first builds, it works completely fine so I'm able to get back the relevant data. However, when I make a change in the database, the values don't update. What am I doing wrong?

The structure I'm using for my data is Devices -> user_id -> data if thats relevant.

edit:
The problem wasn't with my code but flutter web not updating until the browser window was in focus.

Comment: what is this handler.updateData(data); function for?

Comment: It just updates the relevant data on snapshot

Comment: why don't directly passing the snapshot data to the widgets?

Comment: Separating business logic from the UI

Comment: Since you are using Stream which already means that your UI is separated from logic and snapshot regularly listen to the changes but your  handler.updateData(data); is unable to update the UI to check your function or try passing data using snapshot.

Comment: Thank you for you comments. Maybe I should have explained what the function does? my handler is a class that handles my app states. handler.updateData just updates the relevant variables which when updated automatically rebuilds the widgets because I'm using GetX. That wasn't the problem, it was with the streamBuilder that never even ran handler.updateData(). I can tell because the console never printed ('stream updated'). The problem was resolved when I brought the Flutter Web window back into focus so its probably a bug with flutter web. But again, thank you for trying to help!